# MS Access query returning duplicate rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm struggling with a rather simple query. However, given my low level of Access and SQL competency, I've hit a roadblock with my current project. Details are below and thank you all in advance for your patience.

I am combining data from several tables into one large data set that contains all of the fields that are required. I believe the way in which the 'Axle_and_Application_Table' table is joined is causing the query to return duplicate records.

```
SELECT [Purchase Order].POST_DT, 
       Format$(Year([POST_DT]),'00') AS YearField, 
       Format$(Month([POST_DT]),'00') AS MonthField, 
       Format$(Day([POST_DT]),'00') AS DayField, 
       DealerLookup.[Vendor Country], 
       [Purchase Order].VEND_ID, 
       DealerLookup.[Vendor Name], 
       DealerLookup.[Vendor Group], 
       DealerLookup.[Dealer type], 
       [Purchase Order].PRCH_DOC_ID, 
       [Purchase Order].JOB_TYPE_DESC, 
       [Purchase Order].CONTRACT_ID, 
       [Purchase Order].SOLD_TO_CUST_ID, 
       [Purchase Order].LICENCE_PLATE_ID, 
       [Purchase Order].VEHICLE_REG_NBR, 
       [Purchase Order].NAME, 
       [Account Type Lookup].[ACCOUNT NAME], 
       [Purchase Order].location1, 
       [Purchase Order].location2, 
       [Purchase Order].MATERIAL, 
       [Purchase Order].MATL_NAME, 
       [Purchase Order].FOS_TYPE_DESCR, 
       [Purchase Order].SRC_MKT_BRAND_NAME, 
       [Corporate Lookup].Type, 
       [Corporate Lookup].[Brand Groups], 
       [RIM Diameter Lookup].RIM, 
       [Purchase Order].QTY, 
       [Purchase Order].Value1, 
       [Account Type Lookup].[CONTRACT TYPE], 
       [Account Type Lookup].[POLICY FITMENT], 
       [PO Exceptions].[Invalid PO], 
       Axle_and_Application_Table.AXLE, 
       Axle_and_Application_Table.APPLICATION, 
       Axle_and_Application_Table.TBU, 
       Axle_and_Application_Table.[Material Type], 
       Axle_and_Application_Table.TBU, 
       IIf([Material Type]="Service","",[CONTRACT_ID] & [AXLE] & [SRC_MKT_BRAND_NAME] & Replace([FOS_TYPE_DESCR],"Tires","")) AS PID 
FROM ((((([Purchase Order] 
LEFT JOIN DealerLookup ON [Purchase Order].VEND_ID = DealerLookup.[Vendor No]) 
LEFT JOIN [Corporate Lookup] ON [Purchase Order].SRC_MKT_BRAND_NAME = [Corporate Lookup].[BRAND_NAME]) 
LEFT JOIN [Account Type Lookup] ON [Purchase Order].SOLD_TO_CUST_ID = [Account Type Lookup].BILLING) 
LEFT JOIN [PO Exceptions] ON [Purchase Order].PRCH_DOC_ID = [PO Exceptions].[PO Number]) 
LEFT JOIN [RIM Diameter Lookup] ON [Purchase Order].MATERIAL = [RIM Diameter Lookup].MATERIAL) 
LEFT JOIN Axle_and_Application_Table ON [Purchase Order].MATERIAL = Axle_and_Application_Table.Material 
WHERE (((Format$(Year([POST_DT]),'00'))="2015"));
```

Table Structure (Axle_and_Application_Table):

```
Material | Axle    | Application | TBU   | Material Type
-------------------------------------------------------------
12345    | Steer   | Regional    | Truck | Tyre
12346    | Drive   | Municipal   | Truck | Tyre
12347    | Trailer | Regional    | Truck | Tyre
```

[Table Relations Pic...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e11x.png)

I am very new to Access and SQL and appreciate that I will need to considerably develop my skills in this area to try to solve this problem!!

Any help or guidance you can offer on this would be HUGELY appreciated.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please reformat your query, it's very difficult to read now. Also post your table structure, relations and sample data.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. I have made some amendments to my question. I hope these are ok, if there is anything else I can add that will help, I will certainly try.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot know which of the joined tables has multiple matching records and thus creates duplicate records in the result.

You can either look closely at the result: compare 2 duplicate records, are there any columns that are different? If yes, you have found the offending table.

Or: in query design, remove joined tables one by one, check the result afterwards. Once there are no more duplicate records, the last removed table was the culprit.

Then: find a better join criterium, or add a WHERE clause for that table, so that it returns only one record.

// From your relationship window, none of the tables seems to have a primary key?

-> Yes, this is indeed a problem. A relational database depends on primary keys to have defined relations between tables.

In `Axle_and_Application_Table`, `Material` seems to be the obvious choice for primary key, since it's used in the join.
But if it's the one that creates the duplicates, there must be duplicates in `Axle_and_Application_Table.Material`

This is either an error, or you need an additional criterium to join the table to `Purchase Order`.

But before you do anything, you should analyze your database and set or add appropriate primary keys, see e.g. here: [Add or change a table’s primary key in Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-change-a-table-s-primary-key-in-Access-0dde1a80-d913-4d9b-a1b3-061f24ccd991)

Comment: Thanks Andre, that's correct, none of the tables have a primary key. The Access database was actually designed by my predecessor and I am attempting to work with it and add a new table and join (the axle_and_application_table). Should the tables have a primary key?

I have checked, by process of elimination, which table is causing the error. It is the Axle_and_Application_Table table. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Andre, that's brilliant. I'll add the primary keys and look to add a WHERE clause as you have suggested and see what the result is. Thanks again for your help.